# Как под капотом работает RequestDispatcher.forward()?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet

Есть простой сервлет:

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/AdminMenu.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
```

И есть фильтр, который его затрагивает. При определенных сценариях фильтр делает

```
@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request,
                     final ServletResponse response,
                     final FilterChain filterChain)

        throws IOException, ServletException {
    //...
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/AdminMenu.jsp").forward(req, res);
    //...
```

И я все время в лог `tomcat` получаю вот такие `Exception`, код, с точки зрения функционала, работает, только лог засоряет:

```
16-Jun-2017 11:45:03.871 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [SignInServlet] in context with path [/items] threw exception
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at ru.pravvich.servlets.SignInServlet.doPost(SignInServlet.java:30)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at ru.pravvich.servlets.filters.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Почему так происходит?

Если я в фильтре сделал `forward`, то он потом вызывается у сервлета, и падает такая ошибка, или дело не в этом?

Comment: forward из фильтра возвращается куда? Правильный ответ - обратно в фильтр. А дальше что происходит в Вашем фильре? filterChain.doFilter? Т.е. запрос продолжает обрабатываться. Но если в forwarde ответ был сформирован, то дальнейшая попытка что-то записать в ответ приведет к озвученной ошибке. Если делаете forward, который выдаёт заключительный ответ, выполняйте return после него.

Comment: @Sergey большое спасибо за пояснение, добавьте пожалуйста это в ответ что бы я мог его принять.